# $R[x]$ is semiprimitive if and only if $R$ has no non-zero nilpotent ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, nilpotence

Here is the question I'm working on:   Show $R[x]$ is semiprimitive if and only if $R$ has no non-zero nilpotent ideals.

---

Here's my attempt at $semiprimitive \Rightarrow no\space non-zero\space nilpotent\space ideal$:

If $R[x]$ semiprimitive, then $J=(0)$, but we've already shown that every nilpotent element is in $J$, so there are no nilpotent ideals.

($J$ here denotes the Jacobson Radical).

Is this correct? How would I go about proving the other direction?

Comment: A better exercise, I think, would be to prove explicitly that the Jacobson radical of $R[X]$ is $N[X]$, where $N$ is the nilradical of $R$.  The question you are asking about will follow immediately.  So you could your focus your attention on proving that if $f \in R[X]$ is such that $1+fg$ is a unit for all $g$, then $f$ has nilpotent coefficients.

Comment: Ok, just showed that the Jacobson radical of $R[X]$ is $N[X]$. I just don't really see how my question follows immediately. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Wait, I got it. Am stupid. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ssvnormandysr1 Do not ever type "question in title" only.  It is good that it appears in the title, but you also need to transfer it to the body.